# c++ resize 2D vector memory error

Tags: c++, vector

I have a small class:
header file - Grid.h:

```
class Grid
{
public:
  Grid();
  ~Grid();
  bool WriteGridToDSGrdFile(char* FileName);
  bool SetGrid(float *noisearray, int nx, int ny);
private:
  std::vector<std::vector<float>> GridData;
};
```

implementation - Grid.cpp

```
bool
Grid::SetGrid(float* noisearray, int nx, int ny)
{
  for (size_t ix = 0; ix < nx; ix++)
  {
    std::vector<float> row;
    GridData.push_back(row);
    GridData[ix].resize(ny);
    for (size_t iy = 0; iy < ny; iy++)
    {
      GridData[ix].push_back(noisearray[ix*ny + iy]);
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

And then the calling routine (testgrid.cpp):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  int nx = 20; 
  int ny = 10;
  float *NoiseArray = new float[nx*ny];
  std::shared_ptr<Grid> NoiseGrid;
  NoiseGrid->SetGrid(NoiseArray, nx, ny);
  return 0;
}
```

While running in debug mode in MSVS 2013, in `SetGrid` `GridData.push_back(row)`goes bad and I am halted in vector in `bool _Inside(const value_type *_Ptr) const`.

Error message after run:

> First-chance exception at 0x0028F249 in testgrid.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000038. Unhandled
>   exception at 0x0028F249 in testgrid.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x00000038.

I have done these type of 2d manipulations before with great success. I have tried using resize and push_back with same result.
Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: Isn't `NoiseGrid` dangled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the lines:

```
std::shared_ptr<Grid> NoiseGrid;
NoiseGrid->SetGrid(NoiseArray, nx, ny);
```

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr:

The default constructor

> Constructs a `shared_ptr` with no managed object, i.e. empty `shared_ptr`

Use

```
std::shared_ptr<Grid> NoiseGrid(new Grid);
NoiseGrid->SetGrid(NoiseArray, nx, ny);
```

Comment: Thanks.. (wonder how many of these errors I make, and how long it will take to learn :) )